# Separate web hosting and mail server (CPanel)

Tags: web-hosting, email, cpanel, linux

Currently I am having problems with Email service on the same host as my website, so I want to move whole email server to another linux DigitalOcean server but keep the domain name?

My current hosting uses CPanel, how do I host email server on my DigitalOcean Linux Droplet and how should I configure Domain Zone Settings so mails are still pointing to the domain?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no need for a mail server to be on the same machine, in the same building, or even located in the same country as the web server.

In your DNS records you will see MX records, which will indicate the hostname of your mail server. Typically, most people would set this as a sub of their own domain (i.e. mail.example.com) and create an A record to point to the relevant IP address, but you can have any hostname you choose (or simply update the A record).